# Azure Devops Pipeline newbie question for deployment to AWS through intermediate jumpbox server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am a newbie to pipelines, only done a simple yaml to deploy straight to on-prem target server, which is pretty simple and straight forward.

Now I have to create a pipeline to deploy a Azure DevOps GitHub ASP.NET web application to IIS, hosted on AWS hosted Windows Server, via a AWS hosted intermediate Windows Server (jumpbox).

Can I just simply use PowerShell? Or have to SSH in and scp files to jumpbox? I am a bit confusing, can someone provide me a step by step guide on this? What do I need to do? Currently I can only RDP into both jumpbox and web server with admin rights.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi Xstaci, Have you got a chance to check my answer below with suggestions to setup deployment agent to deploy IIS site hosted on your AWS server? Please feel welcome to share your issue/query in new threads when generating your deployment workflow following the documents. Thx and cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have admin access to the Windows server via RDP and established the IIS site on the server, all you need is to configure this Windows machine as an agent for deployment pipeline and it doesn't matter whether the machine is provided by `Azure` or `AWS`. The deployment pipeline should be running on this agent machine through HTTPS requests, to download app artifacts onto the machine first and then copy the app files to the physical location of your app hosted on the machine. Therefore, no need to `SSH in` or `SCP files`.

Here are documents for your reference:

[Deploy an Azure Pipelines agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops)

[Deploy apps to an IIS server on a Windows VM (**Classic**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops&tabs=net) (Use [**deployment groups in a release pipeline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops))

[Azure DevOps — Deployment using **YAML** on IIS: A Step-by-Step Guide | by Jitendra Panchal | Medium](https://medium.com/@jitendra1400/azure-devops-deployment-using-yaml-on-iis-a-step-by-step-guide-585efd8fed60) (Use [**Environment - Virtual machine resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops))